# Hash table sorting and execution time

Tags: c

I write a program to count the frequency word count using hash table, but I don't how to sort it.

I use struct to store value and count.

My hash code generate function is using module and my hash table is using by linked list.

1.My question is how do I sort them by frequency?

2.I am wondering that why my printed execute time is always zero, but I check it for many time. Where is the wrong way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define  HASHSIZE 29989 
#define  FACTOR 31
#define  VOCABULARYSIZE 30
typedef struct HashNode HashNode;
struct HashNode{
    char* voc;//vocabulary
    int freq;//frequency
    struct HashNode *next;//pointed to the same hashcode 
                          //but actually are different numbers
};

HashNode *HashTable[HASHSIZE] = {NULL,0,NULL};//an array of pointers

unsigned int HashCode(const char *pVoc){//generate hashcode
    unsigned int index = 0;
    int n = strlen(pVoc);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < n; i ++)
        index = FACTOR*index + pVoc[i];
    return index % HASHSIZE;
}

void InsertVocabulary(const char *pVoc){//insert vocabulary to hash table
    HashNode *ptr;
    unsigned int index = HashCode(pVoc);
    for(ptr = HashTable[index]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr -> next){//search if already exist
        if(!strcmp (pVoc, ptr -> voc)){
            (ptr->freq)++;
            return;          
        }        
    }
    ptr = (HashNode*)malloc(sizeof(HashNode));//if doesn't exist, create it
    ptr -> freq = 1; 
    ptr -> voc = (char*)malloc(strlen(pVoc)+1);
    strcpy(ptr -> voc, pVoc);
    ptr -> next = HashTable[index];
    HashTable[index] = ptr;
}

void ReadVocabularyTOHashTable(const char *path){
    FILE *pFile;
    char buffer[VOCABULARYSIZE];
    pFile = fopen(path, "r");//open file for read
    if(pFile == NULL)
        perror("Fail to Read!\n");//error message
    char ch;
    int i =0;
    do{
        ch = fgetc(pFile);
        if(isalpha(ch))
            buffer[i++] = tolower(ch);//all convert to lowercase                
        else{
            buffer[i] = '\0';//c-style string
            i = 0;
            if(!isalpha(buffer[0]))
                continue;//blank line
            else //printf("%s\n",buffer);
                InsertVocabulary(buffer);
        }
    }while(ch != EOF);
    fclose(pFile);
}

void WriteVocabularyTOHashTable(const char *path){
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen(path, "w");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        perror("Fail to Write\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < HASHSIZE; i++){
        HashNode *ptr = HashTable[i];
        for(; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr -> next){
            fprintf(pFile, "Vocabulary:%s,Count:%d\n", ptr -> voc, ptr -> freq);
            if(ptr -> next == NULL)
                fprintf(pFile,"\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}

int main(void){
    time_t start, end;
    time(&start);
    ReadVocabularyTOHashTable("test.txt");
    WriteVocabularyTOHashTable("result.txt");
    time(&end);
    double diff = difftime(end,start);
    printf("%.21f seconds.\n", diff); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to your first question, sorting by frequency. Every hash node in your table is a distinct vocabulary entry. Some hash to the same code (thus your collision chains) but eventually you have one HashNode for every *unique* entry. To sort them by frequency with minimal disturbing of your existing code you can use qsort() with a pointer list (or any other sort of your choice) with relative ease.

Note: the most *efficient* way to do this would be to maintain a sorted linked-list during vocab-insert, and you may want to consider that. This code assumes you already have a hash table populated and need to get the frequencies out in sorted order of highest to lowest.

First, keep a running tally of all unique insertions. Simple enough, just add a counter to your allocation subsection:

```
gVocabCount++; // increment with each unique entry.
ptr = (HashNode*)malloc(sizeof(HashNode));//if doesn't exist, create it
ptr -> freq = 1; 
ptr -> voc = (char*)malloc(strlen(pVoc)+1);
strcpy(ptr -> voc, pVoc);
ptr -> next = HashTable[index];
HashTable[index] = ptr;
```

Next allocate a list of pointers to HashNodes as large as your total unique vocab-count. then walk your entire hash table, including collision chains, and put each node into a slot in this list. The list *better* be the same size as your total node count or you did something wrong:

```
HashNode **nodeList = malloc(gVocabCount * sizeof(HashNode*));

int i;
int idx = 0;
for (i=0;i<HASHSIZE;++i)
{
   HashNode* p = HashTable[i];
   while (p)
   {
       nodeList[idx++] = p;
       p = p->next;
   }
}
```

So now we have a list of all unique node pointers. We need a comparison function to send to qsort(). We want the items with the *largest* numbers to be at the head of the list.

```
int compare_nodeptr(void* left, void* right)
{
    return (*(HashNode**)right)->freq - (*(HashNode**)left)->freq;
}
```

And finally, fire qsort() to sort your pointer list.

```
qsort(nodeList, gVocabCount, sizeof(HashNode*), compare_nodeptr);
```

The nodeList array of HashNode pointers will have all of your nodes sorted in descending frequency:

```
for (i=0; i<gVocabCount; ++i)
   printf("Vocabulary:%s,Count:%d\n", nodeList[i]->voc, nodeList[i]->freq);
```

Finally, don't forget to free the list:

```
free(nodeList);
```

As I said at the beginning, the most efficient way to do this would be to use a sorted linked list that pulls an incremented value (by definition all new entries can go to the end) and runs an insertion sort to slip it back into the right place. In the end that list will look virtually identical to what the above code would create (like-count-order not withstanding; i.e. a->freq = 5 and b->freq = 5, either a-b or b-a can happen).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Updated to show OP an idea of what the Write function that outputs sorted data may look like:

```
static int compare_nodeptr(const void* left, const void* right)
{
    return (*(const HashNode**)right)->freq - (*(const HashNode**)left)->freq;
}

void WriteVocabularyTOHashTable(const char *path)
{
    HashNode **nodeList = NULL;
    size_t i=0;
    size_t idx = 0;

    FILE* pFile = fopen(path, "w");
    if(pFile == NULL)
    {
        perror("Fail to Write\n");
        return;
    }

    nodeList = malloc(gVocabCount * sizeof(HashNode*));
    for (i=0,idx=0;i<HASHSIZE;++i)
    {
        HashNode* p = HashTable[i];
        while (p)
        {
            nodeList[idx++] = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }

    // send to qsort()
    qsort(nodeList, idx, sizeof(HashNode*), compare_nodeptr);

    for(i=0; i < idx; i++)
        fprintf(pFile, "Vocabulary:%s,Count:%d\n", nodeList[i]->voc, nodeList[i]->freq);

    fflush(pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    free(nodeList);
}
```

Something like that, anyway. From the OP's test file, these are the top few lines of output:

```
Vocabulary:the, Count:912
Vocabulary:of, Count:414
Vocabulary:to, Count:396
Vocabulary:a, Count:388
Vocabulary:that, Count:260
Vocabulary:in, Count:258
Vocabulary:and, Count:221
Vocabulary:is, Count:220
Vocabulary:it, Count:215
Vocabulary:unix, Count:176
Vocabulary:for, Count:142
Vocabulary:as, Count:121
Vocabulary:on, Count:111
Vocabulary:you, Count:107
Vocabulary:user, Count:102
Vocabulary:s, Count:102
```

Comment: I want to ask that why some number are not sorted?

Comment: But there are some numbers' frequency are not arranged ascending and I don't know where is the problem like 92  176  89 220 221 258 260 388 396 414 912

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Sry, totally my bad. Look at the comparitor in the updated source. it should not be a boolean expression; qsort requies the function return a value < 0 if left should come before right, value = 0 if they're the same, and value > 0 if right should come before left. I've updated the source and the sample. Change yours to have it be right-left rather than left>right. Too much time using C++ has rubbed off my C-skillz. sry.

Comment: OK!I have got it!THx for your time to help! I really appreciate it.:)

Comment: @Liang-YuPan No problem. glad to help, Sorry again for the comparator mistake.